# my username is not in max os x 10.6's passwd file

Tags: operating-system, max

my login name is 'john', in linux, I should see john in the /etc/passwd file.
but in max os 10.6, I can't found such record in /etc/passwd file! Can anybody tell me why and where I can found such record!

[this](https://superuser.com/questions/191330/users-in-etc-passwd-on-mac-os-x) post help me out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/191330/users-in-etc-passwd-on-mac-os-x) over on superuser. To quote from there: "The /etc/passwd file is only consulted when the OS is in single-user mode. The "standard" location for account information on OS/X is the DirectoryService."